# Alternativa a time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un programa que está constantemente verificando si algo en pantalla ha cambiado de lugar mediante un `while` y quisiera hacer una función que ejecute una acción y espere los segundos que yo le indique para volverla a ejecutar, el problema que me encuentro es que si le pongo un `time.sleep(5)` esto pausaría el código 5 segundos y eso no puede pasar, porque necesito estar verificando todo el tiempo
¿cuál sería la solución a este problema?
¿cuál es la alternativa a time.sleep?

solución:

```
import threading

threading.Timer(5, funcion).start()
```

Comment: Te dejo una pregunta que hicieron en SO en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167334/alternative-to-pythons-time-sleep. A ver si te puede servir con tu problema

Comment: No conozco las librerias de tiempo pero se me ocurra que metas en un bucle while al programa durante 5 segundos. Imagino que previamente habra que usar un if para comprobar si ya es el momento de estar en espera.

Comment: Hay muchas formas, depende de tu caso particular. Puedes ejecutar la tarea en otro hilo, puedes usar el propio `while` para ir comprobando la fecha (time.time) y lanzar la función cuando sea oportuno, el módulo `shed` puede también ser una alternativa.

Comment: Habría que conocer algunos detalles más, ¿cuanto tarda de media por iteración tu ciclo por ejemplo? ¿Puede bloquearse en algún paso durante la iteración?, ¿Cómo de importante es la precisión?¿El tiempo empieza a contar desde que la anterior llamada a la función es realizada o desde cuando la anterior llamada retorna?¿Puedes correr la tarea en otro hilo? Si es así ¿la función necesita información generada en el propio ciclo (hay que sincronizar ambos hilos y compartir información de forma segura entre ellos)?...

Comment: @MarioGuiber muchas gracias por el link, y también gracias a NEA y FJSevilla por su colaboración.